# How exactly do I run the -rescan command for bitcoin-qt from console on a Mac?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, rescan

I downloaded the blockchain from a torrent, but when I imported my old wallet.dat file, the balance is not showing.  I am unfamiliar with console operation, so please be as specific as possible.  Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1

Open "Finder".

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Paste this:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
```

Edit `bitcoin.conf` with TextEdit

Add this line:

```
rescan=1
```

Save it, then run Bitcoin-qt.

After you the rescan ends and you quit **don't forget to revert the bitcoin.conf**

### Method 2

Right click Bitcoin-qt

Choose "Show package contents"

Go to  Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt

Run Terminal.

Drag the file to terminal

Type `-rescan`

Press Enter.

**Don't quit Terminal before the rescan ends and you quit Bitcoin-qt**

It's done.

Comment: @ToddAC I assume that even though you have downloaded the blockchain from a torrent you will want your node online so that it can validate you are on the correct fork and download any additional blocks.